# How to drop NA variables from formula

Tags: r

I have a dynamically created formula in a loop, which is used later in some models, for example:

```
y ~ x1+x4+x7+x13+x15
```

In specific circumstances NA elements can be included due to some factors:

```
y ~ x1+x3+NA+x13+NA+x19
```

I would like to drop (omit) NA variables from formula so I get:

```
y ~ x1+x3+x13+x19
```

What is the way to do it in R? My aim is to get a "clean" formula containing only variables.

Comment: It would help if you showed the code for creating the formula.

Comment: By speaking of "NA variables" what you actually mean is "variables that contain NA", correct? Or do you mean "elements that are NA"?

Comment: Add an `na.rm` argument but it's easier to help given the formula.

Comment: The code is very complicated, data dependent and there is no point in giving it here. Sometimes a given variable is not available and NA is included in a formula. Rewriting the code would be much more work intensive than just removing NAs from formula. I tried the update function, but it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `all.vars()` to extract the variables from the formula, which automatically removes `NA` as a variable. Using `unique=FALSE` ensures we keep variables repeated in the formula.  Then we can simply `paste()` the formula back together.

```
v <- all.vars(f, unique=FALSE)

v
# [1] "y"   "x1"  "x3"  "x13" "x19"

as.formula(paste(v[1], "~", paste(v[-1], collapse="+")))
# y ~ x1 + x3 + x13 + x19
```

Data:

```
f <- y ~ x1 + x3 + NA + x13 + NA + x19
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to avoid this when creating the formula. (E.g. checking if `xfoo` is `NA` before icluding it in the formula.) Without it, you will have an invalid formula, and probably the easiest way to treat it would be to convert it to character, omit the NA's, and then convert back to formula. Something like this:

```
f <- function(fml){
  acf <- as.character(fml)
  rhs <- trimws(strsplit(acf[3], "+", fixed=TRUE)[[1]])
  rhs <- rhs[!rhs %in% "NA"]
  rhs <- paste(rhs, collapse = " + ")
  as.formula(paste(acf[2], acf[1], rhs))
}

> f(y ~ x1+x3+NA+x13+NA+x19)
y ~ x1 + x3 + x13 + x19
<environment: 0x0000000019181808>
```

Notice that formula has an environment as well ... so if you decide to use a separate function to convert your formula (like above), it might be useful to return a character string (i.e. skip `as.formula` in the last line) and convert it to the formula when the function has returned. (E.g. `as.formula(f(y~bla + NA + bla))`). Alternatively, you can change the formula's environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses a regular expression to remove the `+NA` or `NA+`

```r
expr <- y ~ NA+x1+x3+NA+x13+NA+x19+NA
as.formula(gsub("\\+\\s*NA\\s*|\\s*NA\\s*\\+", "" , 
                paste0(deparse(expr), collapse = "")))
#R y ~ x1 + x3 + x13 + x19
```